# Magento 2: How to renew the category URL rewrites?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, url-rewrite

I cannot get Magento 2 to renew URL rewrites for categories. I was forced to clear `url_rewrites` table after some weird problems happened after importing categories and products.

Now I get something like `catalog/category/view/s/regntoj/id/304/`.

I have tried the following

- Save the category manually (doesn't work)
- Change URL key and/or "content" and save the category manually (doesn't work)
- "Marketing" > "URL rewrites" and add a rewrite rule (works)

I have more than 200 categories so going to **Marketing > URL rewrites** and manually setup each category will take a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you do this in a setup script.

First, you will need to get a collection of `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category`. You can do this by injecting the classes into the setup script constructor. I won't go too much into detail for this.

Then you would need to get an instance of `Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\Category\CurrentUrlRewritesRegenerator`. There is no service contract that calls the model's method so you need to instantiate the class by injecting the Factory class in your constructor.

Then create a loop through your category collection and pass the object through `CurrentUrlRewritesRegenerator->generate()` function, like so:

```
// pseudo
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $urlRewritesRegenerator->generate($storeId, $category);
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I know it is an accepted answer, but for me it does not work -_- Also the generate functions' docblock says `Generate list based on current url rewrites` which does not seem what we want here (Magento 2.2.5)

Answer (score 2):

Run the module **[Iazel_RegenProductUrl](https://github.com/Iazel/magento2-regenurl)** to fix your URL rewrites, like that:

```
composer require iazel/module-regen-product-url 
php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento iazel:regenurl
```

Comment: This is only for products as far as I can see.

Comment: @Cudos I recently used it, it is for all products and categories

Comment: marked as deprecated by author of repo

Answer (score 2):

This might happen because there is no URL rewrite in Magento. Check your URL rewrites, if that category doesn't exist then create it. In Marketing > URL re-writes > Add URL re-write:

[image: Add URL re-write]

Flush cache, reindex the site and try again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this module which is a successor of the above mentioned, no deprecated, module by iazel:

https://github.com/peterjaap/magento2-regenurl

Follow the instructions in the repository.

It provides this commands:

```
Usage:
 regenerate:product:url [-s|--store="..."] [pids1] ... [pidsN]
 regenerate:category:url [-s]--store="..."] [cids1] ... [cidsN]
 regenerate:category:path [-s]--store="..."] [cids1] ... [cidsN]
```

Answer (score 1):

Below are my steps which finally allow me to delete all the un-necessary URL-rewrites and make the category URL rewrite work in Magento 2.3.0

1. Backup the database
2. Run below in the database
   `delete from catalog_url_rewrite_product_category;
   delete from url_rewrite where entity_type='category' or entity_type='product';`
3. System->Index Management->Update by schedule (Maybe not mandatory, however, I did this as sometimes it takes a lot of time to save a category with this).
   Then Run : php bin/magento indexer:reindex
4. Admin-> Configuration->Catalog->Catalog->Storefront->Change the Use Flat Catalog Category   => No (Mandatory)
5. Admin-> Configuration->Catalog->Catalog->Storefront->Change the Use Flat Catalog Product    => No (Mandatory)
6. Install this module 
   [Regenerate Url rewrites by olegkoval](https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites)
7. Run  bin/magento ok:urlrewrites:regenerate --entity-type=category (Better to run as a background process by adding '&' to at the end of the command)
8. Run  bin/magento ok:urlrewrites:regenerate --entity-type=product
   (Better to run as a background process by adding '&' to at the end of the command)
   (Optionally you can run bin/magento ok:urlrewrites:regenerate in one step)
9. Change back the Change the Use Flat Catalog Category    => Yes
10. Change back the Change the Use Flat Use Flat Catalog Product => Yes

Answer (score -1):

> I recently found this [Magento 2 Module on GitHub](https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites), which fixes all my problems. I can recomend it. You can simply regenerate all your url rewrites for products and categories with the following command:

```
bin/magento ok:urlrewrites:regenerate
```

Comment: I ran this on a database with no entries in the url_rewrite table and I got the URL key already exists error.